# typescript + VS not allowing importing from node_modules while also accessing local files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am using typescript in visual studio 2017, using the default settings in the project TypescriptBuild settings (no tsconfig file):

I have yarn installing into the node_modules folder within the project, and a seperate folder in wwwroot like so:

```
myproject
├── wwwroot ── scripts
├── node_modules ──...
```

using a contrived function like this:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
namespace mynamespace {
    function test(){
       let a = moment(); 
       //intellisense & build for line below only work when commenting out import directive at top of file
       let b = new mynamespace.OtherClass(); 
    }
}
```

I import moment successfully, but have no access to the other classes defined in different files within the same 'scripts' directory. Alternately, if I comment out the import directive, I have access to my other classes (both with intellisense and on build), but obviously cannot access moment from within the node_modules directory.

How do I get access to both moment and other definitions from within my scripts folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem, and this is what I have learned (will be obvious to those working with node & ts all the time):

- use VS code, rather than VS 2017 - it is much better at resolving the imports statements.
- using an npm/yarn project, the node_modules folder is automatically searched when tsconfig contains:

  - "module": "commonjs",
  - "moduleResolution": "node"
- I am using yarn, but equivalent for npm, you can specifically import type definitions

  - yarn add --dev @types/bootstrap
- In the case of seeting up a tsconfig.ts file, allow access to the native node functions by importing:

  - yarn add --dev @types/node